# C# How to save big big int?

Tags: c#, int, biginteger

I need to convert from string this value : `4248035245857302861304475122262852382232831183377907185400973044372526725256648804647567360` and save it in int. Long, Int64 data type doesn't works. I cannot use BigInteger. Double cannot be divided. Some suggestions?

```
    string valorLido;            
            while ((valorLido = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                int leapYear = 0;
                int huluculuFestival = 0;
                int bulukuluFestival = 0;

                long ano = long.Parse(valorLido); 

                if ((ano % 4 == 0) && (ano % 100 != 0 || ano % 400 == 0))
                    leapYear = 1;
                if (ano % 15 == 0)
                    huluculuFestival = 1;
                if (leapYear == 1 && ano % 55 == 0)
                    bulukuluFestival = 1;

                if(leapYear == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine("This is leap year.");
                if(huluculuFestival == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine("This is huluculu festival year.");
                if(bulukuluFestival == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine("This is bulukulu festival year.");
                if((leapYear != 1) && (huluculuFestival != 1) && (bulukuluFestival != 1)) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is an ordinary year.");
                }
            }
```

Input:
`4248035245857302861304475122262852382232831183377907185400973044372526725256648804647567360`

Output:

`This is leap year.
This is huluculu festival year.
This is bulukulu festival year.`

Comment: even `ulong` cannot store that. you need a BigInteger.

Comment: What does it mean to *save* big big int?

Comment: What operations are you going to perform on such numbers? Printing them? Adding them? Looping from i to that number?

Comment: Why can't you use BigInteger

Comment: @ADyson I use online judge URI, and I cannot use BigInteger, cause I got some compilation error, maybe site cannot use .net 4.0 reference.

Comment: I guess you have to ask the maintainers of the site about that

Comment: This has [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) written all over it.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to represent big integer data in a way that is reusable, e.g. to persist it in database, you can either keep it in form of the string, or perhaps serialize it into a byte array.

```
string data = "927349273497234...";
BigInteger big = BigInteger.Parse(data);
byte[] serialized = big.ToByteArray();
```

Now you can use this byte array to save it to database or send it around.

Later on, you can re-create the `BigInteger` object using its constructor which receives a byte array:

```
byte[] data = ...
BigInteger later = new BigInteger(data);
```